# Spring 3.x - Will it play in App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, spring

Spring 3.x is conspicuously absent from the official [Will it play in app engine?](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/web/will-it-play-in-app-engine)

Has anybody got it up and running?

Any issues with the following?

1. Fully annotated controllers?
2. Annotated JSR 303 validation?

Answer (score 2):

Spring is quite broad, so there may be some parts of it that won't work. However, I have deployed a small project using Spring 3 without any major issues.

- Annotated controllers: Can't say about Spring MVC as I used Wicket for the frontend. But the annotations driven DI worked with no problems.
- Annotated JSR-303 Validation: Working perfectly with no issues. Using Apache Bean Validator as provider.
- Apart from those points, I used JPA2 for persistence and the setup was trickier. I would recomend using JDO if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I have had trouble with JSR303 and started another thread, maybe something will jump out at you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196285/spring-app-engine-jsr303